# Re-installing snow leopard but preserving applications and files

Tags: macos

First, is there any benefit to re-installing Snow Leopard?  My current installation was a transfer of an existing installation from a different laptop, and it seems like I've been getting a bit of "slowdown" over the last couple years.  Should I re-install Snow Leopard, and if so what's the best way to go about doing that without losing applications and files?

Answer (score 1):

See [here](https://superuser.com/questions/230576/how-can-i-diagnose-a-slow-mac/230601#230601), [here](https://superuser.com/questions/177206/cleaning-up-mac-os-x/177235#177235) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/217514/clean-install-in-mac-os-x-make-it-faster/217546#217546) and the other topics in the *Linked* section on those pages' sidebars.